# how to check running time and how to force stop program

Tags: algorithm

I'm making Online Judge, but I can't check need to be judged file's running time and I can't stop it. If submitted program have infinite loop, my judge system falls to infinite loop too.
how should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply run the "to be judged files" in a separate thread and kitt it after a time-limit if it has not terminated successfully before.

This way you only need to wait in your time limiting thread and than kill the other one, if it has not finished already.